# ET Geowizards "configuration system failed to initialize Open Main Dialog - Click" error

Tags: et-geowizards

The following error appears when I run any ET Geowizard extension:
"Configuration system failed to initialize Open Main Dialog - Click".
I am using ArcGIS 10.1 on Windows 7 Professional, SP1.
The ET GeoWizard version is 10.2

I have uninstalled and re-installed ET GeoWizard several times with the same error.  I have used the ET GeoWizard Uninstall tool as well with no success.

There is a fleeting mention to this error on an unrelated post but the proposed solution is unclear: it suggests removing a file from a folder which is not on my system, nor does it explain what it does or why the solution works.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks
FH

Comment: I would suggest contacting Ianko support if you haven't already.  I've always found him/them to be prompt and helpful, and interested in finding any problems.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted them and this was there response that worked.

1. Close ArcMap
2. Find a file called "user.config" located in your user folder (see below).
3. Delete the user.config file
4. Start ArcMap

Note that you might have more than one user.config files located in two different folders. Search your user folder
Windows XP
C:\Documents and Settings\UserName
Windows 7, 8 and 8.1
C:\Users\UserName

for user.config file and if you find such a file in a folder where the path contains "Esri", delete that file. If you have more than one user.config files in folders with "Esri" in the path, delete all of them.

UserName is your login name

If you are running Windows 7 or 8 it should be in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\ESRI........

One of mine for example is:

C:\Users\Ianko\AppData\Local\ESRI\DefaultDomain_Path_a11xn45vxuk4d2oixihtmjugblxavdtr\10.0.5.4400\user.config

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I had the same problem with an ArcObjects tool that was throwing the same error on a single user's machine. Worked fine on all the other workstions and I was really scratching my head.